# Error parsing JSONArray(java) to javascript array using spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, json, spring-mvc

I am trying to get a JS array from a `JSONArray` object.
My `JsonConvertor` class:

```
public class JsonConvertor {
public static  JSONArray jsonList(List<Libro> lista)
{
    JSONArray ja=new JSONArray();
    JSONObject jo;
    try {
       for(Libro l: lista){
           jo=new JSONObject();
           jo.put("titulo",l.getTitulo());
           jo.put("autor",l.getAutor());
           jo.put("isbn", l.getIsbn());
           ja.put(jo);
       }
    }catch(JSONException je){
        je.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ja;
}}
```

My controller method:

```
   @RequestMapping("/listaHandle")
   public String listarHandle(Model model) {
      List<Libro> libros = libroServiceImpl.findAll();
      JSONArray ja=JsonConvertor.jsonList(libros);
        model.addAttribute("libros", libros);
        model.addAttribute("libro", new Libro());
        model.addAttribute("ja", ja);
      return "listaHandle";
  }
```

In the JSP tried all this options:

```
 var libros= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(${ja}));
 var libros= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("${ja}"));
 var libros= JSON.parse(${ja}); 
 var libros= JSON.parse("${ja}");
```

All of them cause the following error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I read and this should be because `JSON.parse()` takes a string and not a JSON, but I passed a string or used the `JSON.stringify()` method, and got the same error.

**UPDATE:**

```
    ${ja}=[
    {"titulo":"Java","autor":"Manuel","isbn":"1234"},
    {"titulo":"C","autor":"R‌​icardo","isbn":"4567"},
    {"titulo":"Python","autor":"Jaime","isbn":"1010"}
    ]
```

Comment: Open the HTML source in your browser. How are those rendered?

Comment: "${ja}" ="[{"titulo":"Java","autor":"Manuel","isbn":"1234"},{"titulo":"C","autor":"Ricardo","isbn":"4567"},{"titulo":"Python","autor":"Jaime","isbn":"1010"}]"

Comment: ${ja}=[{"titulo":"Java","autor":"Manuel","isbn":"1234"},{"titulo":"C","autor":"Ricardo","isbn":"4567"},{"titulo":"Python","autor":"Jaime","isbn":"1010"}]

Comment: i dont know if this is what you asked

Comment: Right. But post the full javascript script, how it was rendered. Is it valid javascript?

Comment: the only javascript script i put is <script> var libros=.... </script>